# Test case development to check a logged in user is redirected to different views based on staff status

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-tests

I am a testing a Django Library application, for two types of Users: customers and library staff.

This is the **urls.py**

```
path('dashboard_customer/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='dashboard_customer'),
path('dashboard_staff/', views.LoanedBooksAllListView.as_view(), name='dashboard_staff'),
```

In my views.py, this is the Class-based view for login, wherein if the logged in user is a customer, then on successful login, the customer is redirected to dashboard_customer else if the logged in user is a library staff member, then dashboard_staff.

```
class CustomerLoginView(View):
  def post(self, request):
    username_r = request.POST['customer_username']
    password_r = request.POST['customer_password']

    user = authenticate(request, username=username_r, password=password_r)

    if user is not None:
        # how to write test case to check the below LOC
        login(request, user)
        if user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_staff', args=[]))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_customer', args=[]))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customer_login'))

  def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'catalog/customer_login.html')
```

This is the **test case for Signing up** a user(both customer and library staff):

```
class CustomerLoginTestCase(TestCase):
"""
        Test case for User Log in
"""

def test_login_view_get(self):
    # get request

    response = self.client.get(reverse('customer_login'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'catalog/customer_login.html')

def test_login_view_post_success(self): 
    # post request
    data = {
        'customer_username': 'testuser1',
        'customer_password': '1X<ISRUkw+tuK',
    }
    response = self.client.post(reverse('customer_login'), data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    """
        how to check on successful login, the user is redirected to 
        the appropriate dashboard(dashboard_customer/dashboard_staff) based on if user.is_staff or not?
   """
```

How to develop test case for checking that on successful login, the user is redirected to 'dashboard_customer' if not user.is_staff, else if the logged in user is a library staff, then redirect to 'dashboard_staff'

I am a complete novice in developing test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `follow=True` on your post/get request. It will follow the redirects and you can test the templates used in various views at the end.

Example:

GET:
`response = self.client.get(reverse('customer_login'),follow=True)`

POST:
`response = self.client.post(reverse('customer_login'), data,follow=True)`

You can also do the below in your test case to check the redirected page.

```
self.assertRedirects(response,reverse('your_redirect_url'),status_code=302,target_status_code=200)
```

Comment: I have now included follow=True in both the get/post, however that still doesn't really check whether the customer/library staff is redirected to appropriate url

Comment: Check the updated answer. `Follow=True` won't magically test for what the redirected url is. It just follows the redirection and executes your views that comes in the way and you have to test those with your assert statements. I have given one example of assertRedirects. Incase the customer/library has different templates, you can check it with self.assertTemplateUsed and so on. One way to start would be to print your response object and see what key, value pairs are present and decide how to test your application

Comment: The solution doesn't work: AssertionError: '/catalog/customer_login/' != '/catalog/dashboard_customer/'. The test needs some other check to test two different urls for two different users

Comment: One more thing, did you populate the user table with the usernames and passwords in the setup method? The unittest data are local to the test meaning you cannot use the already existing data in the dev server. Your test case will start executing with all your tables empty. That this the reason the user is not getting recognized by your view and you are getting redirected to the customer_login page time and again. You might want to see the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests

Comment: Did you try populating the user table as i told above? Did you try reading up on that link on how setUp method works?